# Not able to store an object in app data in my uwp app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

I am trying to store an object in appdata of uwp app. I have got some code from google and it is working for an object. Again I am trying to save another object but not able to store. getting error like this

> DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.*"

the object is:

```
public class CustomerAppSettingsResponse
{
    public List<ProductDiscountReason> productDiscountReasons { get; set; }
    public List<OutletDetail> outletDetails { get; set; }
    public List<TaxDetail> taxDetails { get; set; }
    public SettingsResponse settingsResponse { get; set; }
    public ResponseHeader responseHeader { get; set; }
    public List<ProductReturnReason> productReturnReasons { get; set; }
}
```

The code I have used to store data is:

```
private async Task<bool> SaveAppSettings(CustomerAppSettingsResponse objCustomerSettings)
{
    //AppSettings
    try
    {
        StorageFile AppsettingRes = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(AppSettings, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (Stream writeappstream = await AppsettingRes.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            DataContractSerializer objappserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(CustomerAppSettingsResponse));
            objappserializer.WriteObject(writeappstream, objCustomerSettings);
            await writeappstream.FlushAsync();
            writeappstream.Dispose();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to save dtaa");
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can overcome this.

Comment: inside of the using just an fyi you do not need to call dispose on this object 
`writeappstream.Dispose();`

Comment: you could have also done a google search on the error, please read the documentation on [How to Serialize Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx)

Comment: Is that class definition exactly as it is? You're not using `DataContractAttribute` as the error suggests.

Comment: Yeah. As it is I am using the class.

Comment: If I use DataContract then I am not able to Deserialize the json data.                                                                                                       objRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerAppSettingsResponse>(objAppsettingResponse.Body.@return);